# how to access hardware serial port on Raspberry Pi3, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: hardware, raspberrypi, serial-port

I have a Raspberry Pi3 running Ubuntu 16.04.   I am logged in via ssh.

I want to connect a hardware device to UART0 at GPIO pins 8 and 10.   As best I can figure this should correspond to /dev/ttyAMA0.   But I try this shell command and the terminal hangs, the command never returns and even control-C does not work.

```
echo "testing 123" > /dev/ttyAMA0
```

It is not a simple permission problem. I'm in the dailout group.  Here is what "ls" says

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 204, 64 Jun  1 16:26 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

Here is the lines from `dmesg | grep ttyAMA`

```
[    0.833340] 3f201000.uart: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 87, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
```

Comment: Open the device with `screen` like `screen /dev/ttyACM0 <baud rate>`.  Personally I use `byobu-screen`, it might be easier,  it opens session window automatically. Then try typing and press enter. There's other ways, too, but `screen` is easiest.